# how to create attractive looking tabs in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I am trying to get a simple page up that will have four links in the top header menu (horizontally). when clicked one, that html page will load in the body.

So all in all there will be 5 pages.  1 navigation page, and 4 different HTML pages.

I am not sure where to start with this. can someone point me to some good resources?

I did look on google but there is just so much out there i am not sure which one I should be looking at to get my stuff done.

Kind of like how they have it on http://jsbin.com

I am doing this in Rails. so perhaps I can use templates...

Comment: Doesn't Ruby On Rails have a tab control using the Scriptaculous JS framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI has a pretty good [tab component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), it can load content via AJAX too, which it sounds like you need to do.

Comment: in the link you gave. will those 3 be different pages? or just different div's in one html page which are made to look like tabs using jquery?

Comment: The default example uses 3 divs on one page. If you look at the second example on the right, the via AJAX one, it gets the content from a different page dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You always download the [CSS Tab Designer](http://www.highdots.com/css-tab-designer/), set your tab names, choose a selection and then generate the CSS and required HTML. Once you have that done, you can then make them more dynamic through code.

Note: The software is for windows.

Hope this helps some.